# Approve Jenkins Pipeline input step with Bitbucket webhook

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks

I have a pipeline that waits for a merge of a branch to master. It contains an input step:

```
input message: 'Merge complete?', id: 'merge', ok: 'Done'
```

Instead of approving it manually I'd like it to be automatically approved by Bitbucket using post-merge webhook. I know that it's possible to approve it using the Jenkins REST API with the following url: 
https://JENKINS_HOST/JOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/input/Merge/proceedEmpty
Build number changes on every subsequent build. Is it possible to somehow pass the $BUILD_NUMBER variable to Bitbucket, so it could dynamically update its endpoint URL field in post-merge hook configuration?

Comment: I would advise against such a solution. It sounds like a race condition waiting to happen. I would instead use Webhooks to trigger the pipeline once bitbucket has finished

Comment: @smelm thank you for your suggestion, but I can't start the build post-merge because I need some steps to be performed beforehand. Creating separate pipelines for this task would be needlessly complicated. Race condition is very unlikely in this scenario as well. Even if the POST to the URL somehow happens before the input step is reached, it's not going to break anything as that request will simply result in http error 404.

Comment: in that case you might want to consider not waiting for bitbucket but querying it in a loop. Maybe the retry step would help?

Comment: This is the workaround I'm currently using. Input step is in a loop, on approval Jenkins checks state of pull request and breaks the loop if it has been merged. But that still requires manual input. I want it to be approved automatically on merge event.

Comment: You could replace the input step with something like sleep